# Error While Installing Hyper-V emulator for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Win 10 64 bit OS.

Have downloaded and tried installing Visual Studio Emulator for Android but failing with following exception.

> [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal.Net35, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionInitializer.BuildInitializer(TelemetrySessionSettings telemetrySessionSettings)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetryService.get_DefaultSession()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.UserFeedback.Metrics.AppInsightsStartSession(BundleInformation bundle)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.UserFeedback.Metrics.Initialize(Boolean IsBackFromReboot, BundleInformation bundle, ICommand command, CommandLineArgumentsStore commandLine)
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Ux Initialized
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\vsemu' with a timeout of 0 ms
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\vsemu' ownership: True
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Seen existing cache mutex 'Global\vsemu CacheMutex': False
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Aquiring mutex 'Global\vsemu CacheMutex' with a timeout of 60000 ms
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Mutex 'Global\vsemu CacheMutex' ownership: True
>   [1450:1EC8][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i100: Detect begin, 15 packages
>   [1450:1814][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Wait for Detect to complete
>   [1450:1EC8][2016-10-01T21:56:43]i000: MUX:  Detection Phase

Comment: Does your machine fall under the minimum requirements for the Visual Studio Android Emulator?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx#Anchor_0

Ideally this is an issue with a partial VS installation. Try to also repair VS. It seems it's missing an internal VS utility.

Comment: or are you running windows in emulation or inside a VM? Then hyperV is being used to run windows.

Comment: Download this and see what happens: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities/

and use depends.exe to find out what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291224/simsons), you said you're "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources."

I've read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4162f7d3-0e0a-4e29-899c-14f5d34e7675/error-installing-emulator-for-android-component-for-visual-studio-2015-rc-community?forum=vssetup) an answer that says:

> First check if Hyper-V is enabled on your machine in "Turn Windows
> features on or off". You may also need to enable the settings for this
> in your BIOS (VT-x and SLAT).
>
> Installing the Windows 10 tools separately may be faster than
> re-running the full installer,
> https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/install-dev-tools-visual-studio-2015
>
> Use the "If you've already installed Visual Studio 2015 RC" option to
> "Add the tools", this will offer the option to add the visual studio
> emulator for android during setup.
>
> EDIT:
>
> Further to this, it seems that it's not possible to enable Hyper-V on
> my iMac 27" Late 2013 on Insider Preview Build 10074 as VT-x becomes
> disabled every time the machine reboots after selecting to install
> Hyper-V from "Turn Windows features on or off". This causes the
> installation to rollback after the reboot, very frustrating!
>
> EDIT:
>
> This problem occurred after doing a machine refresh, however doing a
> full reset from the recovery options seems to have fixed the issue and
> have now successfully installed Hyper-V.
>
> In this case I have not installed any of the Bootcamp software, I
> initiated the Hyper-V install as soon as the machine booted into the
> desktop environment.
>
> Visual Studio Community 2015 RC is currently installing, I will report
> back if this is also successful
>
> EDIT: SUCCESS!

It is an old answer to a similar question.

I hope it helps.

Juan

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 Single Language, so a Hyper-V cannot be installed. Does it mean that due to this error I cannot install Visual Studio Android Emulator?

Answer (score 1):

have you an Error 0x80070666 in your log or Exception.

Like:

```
[2848:136C][2016-09-21T18:22:28]e000: Error 0x80070666: Process returned error: 0x666
[2848:136C][2016-09-21T18:22:28]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[25D4:2DB4][2016-09-21T18:22:28]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

If yes, you have a Problem with Visual C++ redistributable 2015.

remove Visual C++ redistributable 2015 (both) , repair your VS.
Try to install the Visual Studio Android Emulator again .